# Has anyone dealt with ALTER TABLE statement on multiple medium sized tables?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I did some tests in a few tables that got a bit over 1M records and running a ALTER TABLE statement to add/drop various column types will take somewhere around 13 seconds on my test machine, so i wonder if this is a good alternative to a EAV model?

The reason why i am doing the tests on a few M records is because my specific use case, i don't think i'll have more than 5M records for each dynamically created table, but i'll have few hundred tables and the fields will be searched a lot. I also don't think fields will change that often.

Does anyone uses this workflow to dynamically add columns to tables as opposite to the EAV model? If so, how does it compare?

Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint does :}

Comment: In general, something is wrong with your data model if you are commonly adding and removing columns from a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - think custom fields.

Comment: If the normal workflow of your application requires running `ALTER TABLE` frequently then a relational database is not the proper storage for its data. You either continue to use your current implementation of EAV of switch to one of the many noSQL database systems.

Comment: If you can upgrade to MySQL 5.7, then the new JSON datatype is a perfect alternative to EAV

Answer (score 0):

Using `ALTER TABLE` for EAV (aka "extensible fields", "custom fields", etc) is invariably a bad idea. While in most cases appending new `NULL`able columns to an existing table is not an overly expensive operation, the removal, reordering, and non-append insertion of columns is very expensive - often requiring all of the data to be copied to a new destination table and deleting the original (which must be done in a transaction, often with table-level locking), don't forget about dropping and recreating foreign-key constraints too.

Ideally, EAV data should be stored in a dedicated EAV database system that can handle sparse data and enforce the special constraints required for EAV (e.g. restricting which EAV attributes are allowed for a given type of parent entity or other business rules). Often, this is done with a NoSQL or Document-Store database (e.g. MongoDB).

However, if your only tool is MySQL and you can't run other types of servers, you're better-off adopting an actual EAV pattern for storing your data, such as below (pseudo-code SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE Attributes (
    AttributeId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Type smallint /* some enum you define */
)

CREATE TABLE AttributeHolders (
    HolderId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE AttributeValues (
    HolderId bigint FK AttributeHolders.HolderId,
    AttributeId bigint FK Attributes.AttributeId,

    TextValue nvarchar(100) NULL,
    IntValue  bigint NULL,
    DateValue datetimeoffset NULL
)
```

You would then need to add an FK to `AttributeHolders.HolderId` from your other entity tables, and add a constraint that prevents different instances of those entities sharing the same `HolderId`.

...which is a problem left to the reader. There are no easy, cross-platform solutions, unfortunately. Though one option is to create a `SEQUENCE` object that serves as the identity value source for the variety of entities that can be `Holders`.